# The easy way to modify icon color & its background color

Tags: color, icon, background, mobile, mobile-first

Sorry for the question. I am new to graphic design. I am a developer. I just bought an icon bundle for iOS & Android applications. I found that the colors are only black & while. The icons come with some formats such as PNG, PSD. I just want to modify icons colors. I only used Windows Mspaint application before.

- Can someone guide me how to do?
- What software do you recommend?
- How can I extract an icon from set of icons in a big PNG file?

Note that the purpose of using these icons is for iOS & Android applications.

Comment: I highly recommend Photoshop even if you don't get the newest version but Gimp could still be good for this.

Answer (score 1):

a PSD is a [photoshop](http://www.photoshop.com/) file. Here is a list of [Free Adobe Photoshop Alternatives](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/11-free-alternatives-softwares-to-adobe-photoshop/).

This will be the best way to alter your icons.

Comment: Thanks!. I thought about Photoshop before but it is too big for me since I am new to it.

Answer (score 1):

This will be very easy for you.

1. Photoshop CC, all cloud based software around $20 US a month
2. [GIMP](http://gimp.org) is free and very close to the above

Fast way to alter color of each icon:

1. Upload icons
2. Go to "layer style" then "color overlay"
3. Pick color
4. Save again as PNG

This way, your icon will recolor and your background stays transparent.